# How to Center UI View when in landscape & portrait?

Tags: ios, objective-c, user-interface, uiimageview

I having trouble centering 2 UIImages and a Layer when Orientation changes.

here is what i did to center it

```
   _colorLayer = [CALayer layer];
CGRect frame = self.hueImageView.frame;
CGSize superviewSize = self.hueImageView.superview.frame.size;
self.hueImageView.center = CGPointMake((superviewSize.width / 2), (superviewSize.height / 2));
self.checkeredView.center = CGPointMake((superviewSize.width / 2), (superviewSize.height / 2));
self.labelPreview.center = CGPointMake((superviewSize.width / 2), (superviewSize.height / 2));
```

this works fine in portrait. but when i rotate the images do not go to the middle .

the project is on my github
https://github.com/RK905/NewColorPic/blob/master/NewColorPic/NEOColorPickerHSLViewController.m

Comment: set the frame in viewDidLayoutSubviews

Comment: Are you using autolayout or autoresizingmask?

Comment: Figured it out. Needed to refresh UI View with setNeedsDisplay

Answer (score 0):

just set the center from your superView to all other views. superView.center should do it. No fights with height/2 and width/2 .

If you would use constraints, you will not need to set it again. Just align the views to the center.y and center.x of the superView. No fight with orientations because the constrain center will automaticly move also